# Does a beis din have reshus to punish a nochri?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, shulchan-aruch, noachide-laws, maseches-makos

According to [Shulchan Aruch EH P22S2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.22.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ושמאי והלל גזרו על ייחוד כותית נמצא כל המתייחד עם אשה שאסור להתייחד עמה בין ישראלית בין כותית מכין את שניהם מכת מרדות

This seems to suggest that the beis din would give malkos to the (presumably) nochri כותית for violating a gezera placed on Jews (or bringing a Jew to violate it).

If I am understanding this correctly, I have the following questions:

1. Is the aveyra on the part of the כותית lifney iver?
2. Is lifney iver a mitzvah for non-jews?
3. Is a beis din allowed to give malkos/malkos mardus to a non-jew.

Comment: A good question, +1. You seem to confuse "have the right" and "take the right". See for example https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.46a.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&qh=%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%94%20%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9A - They stoned one who they didn't have the right to stone. The excuse was that they authorized themself to declare an emergency and override Biblical laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the issue of lifnei iver for a non jew,  Tosfos in Avodah Zara 15b (L'oved) says that a non jew does not have the issur of lifnei iver. However, the Pri Migadim in Ginas Veradim (klal 43) says that a non jew does have the issur of lifnei iver. The Minchas Chinuch (mitzvah 232) argues,  and the Sdei Chemed (6:23) brings a whole list of Achronim who argue and mentions Tosfos as well as one who argues.

So in answer to your questions;

1. Possibly, although more probable that it's because an aveira was done through her, just like an animal would get killed because it was the subject of causing someone to sin
2. Machlokes Achronim
3. In Israel when there's a Sanhedrin they punished non Jews as well (see Pesachim 3b story with R' Yehuda ben Beseira)

Comment: > In Israel when there's a Sanhedrin they punished non Jews as well (see Pesachim 3b story with R' Yehuda ben Beseira). 



Does that mean that takanas chachamim can apply to non-jews?

Comment: Makos mardas especially, was used by bais din as they saw fit when the need arose. So if society required it, then why shouldn't it apply to everyone living there. All I'm saying is that Bais din definitely meted out punishments to non Jews in Israel